# Animation Nodes - Multiple Particle Hair systems distribution, and mimic child particles

Tags: particles, animation-nodes, hair

I followed a tutorial on how to distribute object with particle hair system:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GahQXc8QQuc

I also add a few nodes from another tutorial to get the whole collection distributed. 
Everything so far good. But know I'm stuck. I don't know, because I anyway don't know AN Nodes, on how to do a few other things, and hope someone can help Me.

1. How to distribute objects for a given particle system? So I can have few and add new ones. So basically the as with normal multiple particle systems.
2. How to distribute object on child particles (I already know, that this isn't implemented yet), or how to mimic it.

For now that's all. Attaching blend with the scene, and grass objects etc.

File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ask8lAGClZG0miUaC9aVIGIRaOOJQnQO

Animation result of grass on another test file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wIarldHeq8w6AiKnmlH-1B3k85MJzQ5R

Node setup for actual result:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access multiple particle system of an object from `Particle systems` socket of `Particle system from object` node. Which will give you a list of particle system available on particular object. You can simply access those using `Get List Element` node by providing index value. You are currently using `Active` particle system only.

Here is an example:

[image]